# Toast in Try/Catch numberformatexception

Tags: android, try-catch, android-alertdialog, toast, numberformatexception

I am tring to use a Toast in my Try/Catch but when it catches a wrong input the toast does not show up. I cannot find the error in the code, please help me out here.

this is a short part of the code which includes the try/catch block:

```
 else{
      try{
          Integer.parseInt(score_1.getText().toString());
          Integer.parseInt(score_2.getText().toString());
          ArrayList_matches.get(position_match).score_1 = score_1.getText().toString();
          ArrayList_matches.get(position_match).score_2 = score_2.getText().toString();
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


      } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
          Toast.makeText(Game_activity.this, "Wrong input, numbers only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

     }
```

Comment: You should use log.e(tag, message);

Answer (score 0):

So simple use

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong input, numbers only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

instead of

```
Toast.makeText(Game_activity.this, "Wrong input, numbers only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And if you want to debug then use

```
Log.d("TAG","YOUR MSG");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set some default integer values for score1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 try {

     Integer.parseInt(score_1.getText().toString());
     Integer.parseInt(score_2.getText().toString());
     ArrayList_matches.get(position_match).score_1 = score_1.getText().toString();
     ArrayList_matches.get(position_match).score_2 = score_2.getText().toString();
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
     public void run() {
         Toast.makeText(Game_activity.this, "Wrong input, numbers only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     });

 }
```

I highly recommend to Use `Log` inside catch.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

may be its not a NumberFormatException. please give wrong input that is not in number format,